# Can't find Signing Interface - Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, strongname

I'm working on a releasing an open-source Nuget package for the first time with the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition (previously using 2012). Every reference for strong-name signing says that getting the interface to select my signing key is easy:

> 1. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project, and then choose Properties.
> 2. Choose the Signing tab.
>
> From MSDN: ["How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx)

The problem is that of an ignorance and abasement...I can't get to this tab! Did the location change between these two versions? Below is what I get when looking at my Project Properties interface.

[image: my view of the project properties interface]

Have tried opening with admin permissions, have tried making a (foolishly naiive) edit to my `project.json` file to specify `compilationOptions->keyFile` as a get. None of this seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Project is an Application Project and not a Class Library Project.